# Touchend iOS won't fired if leaving screen slowly

Tags: javascript, ios, touch, dom-events

I build a Slider that handles `touchstart`, `touchend` and `touchmove` events.

It works fine on Android and iOS.
Only when I'm moving my finger on iOS slowly out of the screen the `touchend` event won't fire.
After I put my finger back on the screen the touchend event  fired immediatly but not the touch start.

Does anybody know why the touchend event won't fire?

I searched for hours to find a solution.
I tried `touchcancel` but it doesn't help.

**Javascript:**

```
this.element = document.createElement('div');
this.element.classList.add('slider');
parent.appendChild(this.element);
//other stuff

this.element.addEventListener('touchstart', ()=> {
    console.log('start');
});
this.element.addEventListener('touchend', ()=> {
    console.log('end');
});
this.element.addEventListener('touchmove', ()=> {
    console.log('move');
});
```

**css:**

```
.slider{
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
}
```

**EDIT #1**

I tried also `gestureend` but it doesn't help.

I found out that it only doesn't fire when I slide to the side with the homebutton (I am in landscape mode).

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the exact same problem while building a slider in a Vue.js app for ios, wrapped in Cordova.

I didn't find the cause of this behaviour where `touchend` events don't fire at the 'button-end' of the ios device, but I did create a workaround.

I'm assuming this is no longer relevant for you, but it might help someone else who has this problem:

Context of my events (for non-Vue users `this.$refs.profileSlider` is just a DOM reference to the element wrapping my slider):

```
  this.$refs.profileSlider.addEventListener('mousedown', this.lock, false);
  this.$refs.profileSlider.addEventListener('touchstart', this.lock, false);

  this.$refs.profileSlider.addEventListener('mousemove', this.drag, false);
  this.$refs.profileSlider.addEventListener('touchmove', this.drag, false);

  this.$refs.profileSlider.addEventListener('mouseup', this.move, false);
  this.$refs.profileSlider.addEventListener('touchend', this.move, false);
```

To ensure that the `move()` function is called even when the `touchend` event doesn't fire (when a user swipes off the end of the screen), I added a conditional check at the end of the `touchmove` handler, here called `drag`:

```
  // Rest of touchmove handler here
  const unified = this.unify(e);

  if (unified.clientX >= window.innerWidth - 3 || unified.clientX <= 3) {
    this.$refs.profileSlider.dispatchEvent(new TouchEvent('touchend', e));
  }
```

`e` in this function is the context of the the `touchmove` event. This way the `drag()` handler will run as normal, then check if the `touchmove` event occurred within 3px (this sensitivity works for my purposes) of either side of the screen. If so, it fires off a new `touchend` `TouchEvent` and passes it the same `e` value as the previous `touchmove`.

This resolves the problem of `touchend` not firing when a user's touch continues off the edge of the screen. Instead `touchend` is fired preemptively, just before the swipe would otherwise exit the screen.

// For reference, the `unify` function called in the above block simply checks for `changedTouches` on the event, and returns the first `changedTouch` if it exists:

```
unify(e) {
  return e.changedTouches ? e.changedTouches[0] : e;
}
```